# Injectable factory with Macwire

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

I'm teasing out MacWire for dependency injection.

One thing that i found useful with Guice is the assisted inject, to autowire a factory that would help you to create some service that needs run parameters.

Is there something similar with Macwire ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injectable factories are supported, but are not really a feature of MacWire, rather in MacWire's spirit, you can "just use Scala".

In this case, you can use function types. Following the Guice examples, let's say you want to create a `Payment` parametrized by a `startDate: Date` and `amount: Money`. You could define a dependency:

```
val paymentFactory = (startDate: Date, amount: Money) => wire[Payment] 
                     // or create the payment in any other way
```

and then use it as a normal dependency:

```
class ServiceUsingPayment(paymentFactory: (Date, Money) => Payment)
val serviceUsingPayment = wire[ServiceUsingPayment]
```

You could also use a type alias to avoid repeating the function signature, and use that alias when declaring another service's dependencies (as in `ServiceUsingPayment` above):

```
type PaymentFactory = (Date, Money) => Payment
```