# Assisted injection with MacWire in Scala

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

I've been toying around with MacWire for few days. I find it quite elegant. Although, experimental, i'm thinking about using it for a project that i'm working on.

However I've not been able to grasp how to create something similar to an assisted-injection with it. In other words, how to inject a factory ?

Comment: Same question asked a day before is already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457400/injectable-factory-with-macwire/25828840#25828840